# Secure web API with token

Tags: php, ajax, rest, http

I need help to understand how to secure an API.

I am working on a project based on a RESTful API with a JSON response.

I have a web application and a mobile application which send requests like this:

```
http://my-server.com/api/v1/products
```

with a protocol (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE) and eventually parameters.

My concern is to secure these calls, from both applications.
Today I am just checking if this is an Ajax call:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
    {
        if ($method == 'GET')
        {
            return $data = $this->stores_model->get_all($select);
        }
    }
```

But mobile does not send xmlhttprequest, right?

I think I have to check a token stored in the session or locally for the mobile. I have also seen some points about the CSRF token, regenerate each time.

This is all I know about security. How do I get to understand more regarding my architecture?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very deep topic, but first of all you should have SSL installed on your server. I think this is a starting point for the security.

For your JavaScript and browser clients, you can enable cors on your API. You can get more information about cors [here](https://enable-cors.org/).

For application clients, you can consider to implement [OAuth](https://oauth.net/). OAuth 2 is widely used these days, easy to implement but you can also go with OAuth 1. Check their differences and see which one suits for your project. You can find a good comparison [here](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth_1_versus_oauth_2.html) about them. There are good implementations of them out there, so check them out. One example for the [OAuth 2](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/).

Comment: you are right i am going to read a bit on oauth2 this seems to be a good starting point ;) 
thanks